# Selecting by attribute using Python and a list

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, select-by-attribute

I have been using this script to select a feature using Python:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.selectByExpression('\"Declividad\"= value', QgsVectorLayer.SetSelection)
selection = layer.selectedFeatures()
```

But now, I need to select the values for Declividad from a list.

For exemple: list = [10,11,12], so I want to select the values 10,11 and 12 for Declividad.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could juse use an expression like:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
my_list = [10, 11, 12]
values = ','.join(str(x) for x in my_list)
layer.selectByExpression('\"Declividad\" IN (' + values + ')', QgsVectorLayer.SetSelection)
```

Comment: Oh! that did the trick :) thanks!

Comment: @caiovillaca - Most welcome! Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try the **IN** operator :

```
layer.selectByExpression('\"Declividad\" IN (\'10\',\'11\','\12')', QgsVectorLayer.SetSelection)
```

Or do u need to dynamically reference the list name ?

Comment: yep, I need it to read the values from the list...